# Full year calendar in C#

Tags: c#, calendar

So was looking to see how to code a calendar in C# which is easy if your using asp.net. However, I'm using console application because i'm required to do so. Now coding for a one month was not to bad but I can't figure out how to code a whole year (January-December).

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int current = 0;
            int skip = 0;
            int day = 1;
            int endDay = 31;
            string line = "  Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat";
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            line = "";
            while (skip < current)
            {
                line += "    ";
                skip++;
            }
            while (day <= endDay)
            {
                while (current < 7 && day <= endDay)
                {
                    line += String.Format("{0,4}", day);
                    current++;
                    day++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(line);
                line = "";
                current = 0;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

after doing so this will display a one month calendar so the question is how could I display a full year calendar while still using console application and from the codes I already have?

Comment: Your assignment should have specified how output should look like. Please check. If not - I think the best option would be to ask teacher to post clarifications to this question so they can save time on checking homework too.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this. I tried to add comments for explanation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Loop 12 times (once for each month)
    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        // Get the first day of the current month
        var month = new DateTime(2017, i, 1);

        // Print out the month, year, and the days of the week   
        // headingSpaces is calculated to align the year to the right side            
        var headingSpaces = new string(' ', 16 - month.ToString("MMMM").Length);
        Console.WriteLine($"{month.ToString("MMMM")}{headingSpaces}{month.Year}");
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));
        Console.WriteLine("Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa");

        // Get the number of days we need to leave blank at the 
        // start of the week. 
        var padLeftDays = (int)month.DayOfWeek;
        var currentDay = month;

        // Print out the day portion of each day of the month
        // iterations is the number of times we loop, which is the number
        // of days in the month plus the number of days we pad at the beginning
        var iterations = DateTime.DaysInMonth(month.Year, month.Month) + padLeftDays;
        for (int j = 0; j < iterations; j++)
        {
            // Pad the first week with empty spaces if needed
            if (j < padLeftDays)
            {
                Console.Write("   ");
            }
            else
            {
                // Write the day - pad left adds a space before single digit days
                Console.Write($"{currentDay.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, ' ')} ");

                // If we've reached the end of a week, start a new line
                if ((j + 1) % 7 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

                // Increment our 'currentDay' to the next day
                currentDay = currentDay.AddDays(1);
            }
        }

        // Put a blank space between months
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress and key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

[image]